# Is it possible to prove $|\sin(x)| \leq 1$, $|\cos(x)| \leq 1$ and $|\sin(x)| \leq |x|$ algebraically?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I know that we can prove $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: |\sin(x)| \leq |x|$ by using the mean value theorem on $\sin(x)$, it's also easy to see that when $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $|\sin(x)| \leq 1$, $|\cos(x)| \leq 1$ just by properties of real numbers and the order defined on them,  but is there a way to obtain these results algebraically or in more general spaces?

Imagine that we are in a commutative ring with a topology defined on it. I want to define the functions $\sin(X) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{X^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}$ and $\cos(X) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{X^{2n}}{(2n)!}}$ for the $X$'s where the series converge. It's easy to show that $\sin^2(X)+\cos^2(X)=1$ by algebraic manipulations. Many other properties of $\sin(X)$ and $\cos(X)$ will also generalize easily but unfortunately I can't show that those 3 inequalities necessarily hold in a general situation.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, from $\sin^{2}(x) + \cos^{2}(x) = 1$, it follows that $\vert \sin(x) \vert \leq 1$ and $\vert \cos(x) \leq 1$.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$, yes, I know that it follows easily from that, and I've said in my post that there's no problem for the case $X=\mathbb{R}$. Can you say this for a general space $X$? Can you prove it this way when $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ for example or other general spaces? I doubt.

Comment: What exactly is "$\frac 1 {(2n+1)!}$" in an arbitrary ring?

Comment: @Tomas: That is a good question. Actually I had the set of matrices in my mind. It's common to generalize $e^X$ for matrices by using the Taylor series of $e^x$ and most identities of $e^x$ still hold for the set of matrices such that $AB=BA$. I guess we need to give the ring a $\mathbb{Q}$-module structure but your question means that I need to think more over this. But we could ignore it for now. I mean, it has nothing to do with that part of the question that asks for an algebraic proof of the identity $|\sin(x)| \leq |x|$. Could you prove it for $\mathbb{R}$ algebraically?

Comment: We can think it in another way and it is much easier. Use area property of a circle for your last inequality. Proof will not be very abstract but algebraic.

Comment: Well, these properties don't hold in $\mathbb{C}$, which is a very nice topological ring. Thus you can't prove these properties algebraically. You need something more, like the order on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Samprity: Please explain.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Good point. Now I remember that $\sin(z)=-2$ has a solution in $\mathbb{C}$ and $|sin(z)|=2$ in this case. So we can't generalize two of those properties. Thanks for reminding it. How about $|\sin(x)| \leq |x|$? Any counterexamples you have in mind?

Comment: $\lvert \sin (x+iy)\rvert^2 = \sin^2 x + \sinh^2 y$, so anything with a sufficiently (depending on the real part) large (in absolute value) imaginary part does. In particular, $\lvert \sin (iy)\rvert = \lvert \sinh y\rvert > \lvert y\rvert$ for every $y \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Take a circle, a radius, an angle over it say $x < \frac{\pi}{2}$. Draw a tangent to the circle perpendicular to your radius. Extend the line of your angle to meet the tangent line. join the end of the radius and the point where the line of the angle cross the circle. Now you shall get three areas 1. an area inside the circle and a traingle, 2. Area under the circle and inside the angle, 3. Area under the angle and the tangent line. Evaluate them and compare. You shall get your desired inequality. I should add the picture but I do not know how to add it.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks. Would you please write this as an answer so I can choose it?

Comment: @Samprity: Thank you Samprity, your idea is clear enough. It's possible to add pictures when you write answers, but you can't add pictures in comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since in the topological ring $\mathbb{C}$ none of these properties hold - we have

$$\begin{align}
\lvert \sin(x+iy)\rvert^2 &= \lvert \sin x \cosh y + i\sinh y \cos x\rvert^2 = \sin^2 x\cosh^2 y + \sinh^2 y\cos^2 x = \sin^2 x + \sinh^2 y\\
\lvert \cos (x+iy)\rvert^2 &= \lvert \cos x \cosh y - i\sin x \sinh y\rvert^2 = \cos^2 x\cosh^2 y + \sin^2 x\sinh^2 y = \cos^2 x + \sinh^2 y
\end{align}$$

for $x,\, y \in \mathbb{R}$, so $\sin$ and $\cos$ are unbounded and grow exponentially with the imaginary part - one cannot prove any of these properties purely algebraically.

Some further structure is required, like in the case of $\mathbb{R}$ the order.