# $ |\sin (x) | \leq 1$ by it's definition

Tags: real-analysis, definition

I was told that it can be shown that $|\sin(x)| \leq 1$ by its definition

> $\sin (z):= \frac{1}{2i} \bigl( (\exp(iz)-\exp(-iz)\bigr) $

I am aware that as soon as I choose $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and substitute it into the equation, the equation itself becomes real $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

**My approach**:

$ |\sin (z)| \leq 1 \implies |\sin z|^2 \leq 1 \implies \sin z \cdot \overline{ \sin(z)} \leq 1$ by definition. Since I want to show this for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ it applies that $z= \overline{z}$ and I substitute $x$ into the definition.
$$ \frac{1}{2i}((\exp(ix)-\exp(-ix))\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{2i}((\exp(-ix)-\exp(ix))\right) \\ \implies \frac{1}{4}( \exp(0)-\exp(2ix)-\exp(-2ix)\exp(0)) \\ \iff  \frac{1}{4}(2-\exp(2ix)-\underbrace{\exp(-2ix)}_{ \in ]0,1]})$$
So this seems to be pretty near to the result I want to proof, however, $\exp(2ix)$ can get sufficiently large for big $x$ so I doubt that my approach is correct.

Any hints, ideas, corrections to keep me going?

**Similar Questions**

[Is it possible to prove $|\sin(x)| \leq 1$, $|\cos(x)| \leq 1$ and $|\sin(x)| \leq |x|$ algebraically?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462925/is-it-possible-to-prove-sinx-leq-1-cosx-leq-1-and-sinx-l)

There's a comment saying that $|\sin(x)| \leq 1$ follows by $ \sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) =1 $ which I don't see why.

Comment: Note that for non-real $z$, you don't generally have $\lvert\sin z\rvert \leqslant 1$. If you are willing to work with $\lvert e^{ix}\rvert = 1$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, it's fairly direct.

Comment: If you accept $\sin^2 x  \cos^2 x = 1$ (which is essentially the Pythagorean theorem), then you get that $\sin ^2 x =1-\cos^2 x \le 1$ and so $|\sin x| \le 1$

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, so the first line where my implication chain starts is wrong. For $x \in \mathbb{R}$ I don't understand why $| e^{ix} |=1$ if that would be true for $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ then it is indeed direct to show.

Comment: For non real $x$ this is simply false, take $2i$ for example.. For real $x$, $\sin^2$ and $\cos^2$ are bigger than zero, so if $\lvert \sin(x)\rvert > 1$ then $\sin^2 + \cos^2 > 1$ a contradiction.

Comment: $\lvert e^z\rvert^2 = e^z\overline{e^z} = e^ze^{\overline{z}} = e^{z+\overline{z}} = e^{2\operatorname{Re}z} \Rightarrow \lvert e^z\rvert = e^{\operatorname{Re}z}$

Comment: As Daniel already pointed out as well, my good old college notes state that if the input is complex, the range of sinz and cosz are unbounded, and certainly the absolute value of sinz is not bounded by 1