# How to prove $|\sin x| \leq 1$, $|\cos x| \leq 1$ in a simplistic way without resorting to pictures?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

So my question is  looking at if there is a way to show in a less advanced way than this question:
[Is it possible to prove $|\sin(x)| \leq 1$, $|\cos(x)| \leq 1$ and $|\sin(x)| \leq |x|$ algebraically?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462925/is-it-possible-to-prove-sinx-leq-1-cosx-leq-1-and-sinx-l) if it is possible to show these inequalities?

I ask because I'm working through Spivak's Calculus and it dawned on me that up to this point I haven't "shown" that $|\sin (x)| \leq 1$, $|\cos(x)| \leq 1$ are actually true. We've taken them as true, but I would've thought that since they appear to be "simple" expressions that we would've shown these properties at this point. This came up because I was trying to prove that $\cos(x)$ is continuous everywhere but the only idea I have of doing this is by using the mean value theorem which hasn't been addressed yet (I'm on Chapter 8: Least Upper Bound and Uniform Continuity).

Comment: What are the definitions of $\sin$ and $\cos$ then? I'm very used to unit circle point $(x,y)$ coordinates. consider $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ for example.)

Comment: In the trig circle, $\sin$ is the ratio $\frac {y} {\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}}$. Suppose this ratio is more than 1. You should arrive at a contadiction.

Comment: It depends on your definitions. What are those functions for you?

Comment: If I remember correctly Spivak actually defines the trigonometric functions in a very rigorous way. (which is great). He also proves the basic property $\sin ^2(x)+\cos ^2(x)=1$, from here it easily follows that $|\sin x|, |\cos x|\leq 1$.

Comment: You haven't told us the definitions of $\cos x,\sin x$ you are using.

Comment: @Mark, there is a whole chapter dedicated to the trig functions. I skimmed through it and  looking at it again right now, he does define the functions as hamam did below. So it appears I was getting ahead of myself.

Comment: @zhw. an explicit one hasn't been given up to this point of my readings, but observe my comment above.

Comment: Yes, Spivak defines these functions in a rigorous way, and also the number $\pi$. His definition is both formal and giving the correct geometric intuition. This is something I really like in this book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Pythagore's Theorem and by definition, we have for all reals $ x$

$$\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$$

$$\implies \cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)\le 1$$

$$\implies -1\le \cos(x) \le 1$$
$$\implies |\cos(x)|\le 1.$$

Answer (score 3):

A rigorous way to define the trigonometric functions is to define $\cos$ on $[0, \pi]$ as the inverse function of
\begin{equation}
\arccos(x) = \int_x^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} dt
\end{equation}
This function $\cos$ is then extended to $[-\pi, +\pi]$ by parity and then to $\mathbb R$ by periodicity.

With this definition, $\cos(x)$ is necessarily in $[-1, 1]$ for all $x$.

Comment: Really? I thought $cos$ is introduced first, then $arccos$, let alone definite integrals.

Comment: @peter.petrov You should take a look at Spivak's calculus book. There is a full chapter where he gives this rigorous definition of trigonometric functions. With his method it is really easier to define $\arccos$ first.

Comment: @peter.petrov $\cos$ is introduced first in high school with heuristic geometric arguments, but it is not a rigorous definition.

Comment: Oh... OK... I see. Yeah, I don't think we defined these rigorously even in real analysis. We just assumed we know what $sin$ and $cos$ are.

Comment: Of course, in a first course in real analysis you can't give such complicated definitions. Trust me, I also don't give a rigorous definition of trigonometric functions to my students in a real analysis course, as much as I like to be formal. But at some point you might want to look for a rigorous definition. There are many ways to define trigonometric functions formally-using power series or differential equations. But what I like about Spivak's method is that his definition is rigorous AND also preserves the geometric intuition.

Comment: The conversation on this is a lot more in depth than I first thought it was going to be. What look "simple" really isn't a simple concept at all....

Answer (score 2):

This is usual high school stuffL first, those functions are defined as the fraction of one leg of a rught triangle over the hypotenuse. That's always less than $\;1\;$ . Then these functions are extended to the whole real numbers by means of the trigonometric circle (the canonical circle of radius one), and once again the absolute value of those functions is always less *or equal*$\;1\;$ ....that's all.

Comment: Exactly, this is a good proof for high school. But for advanced mathematics I don't feel like this definition is rigorous enough. At the very least it leads to a lot of questions about why these functions are well defined.

Comment: @Mark I think the OP mentioned they need a simplistic answer and not some advanced stuff.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, Spivak defines the sine as the solution of the differential equation with initial conditions
$$y''+y=0,\quad y(0)=0,\enspace y'(0)=1$$
and $\cos x=y'(x)$. You deduce instantly that
\begin{align}
(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)'&=(y(x)^2+y'(x)^2)'=2y(x)y'(x)+2y'(x)y''(x)\\
&=2\bigl(y(x)y'(x)-y'(x)y(x)\bigr)=0
\end{align}
so $\; \sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=\sin^20+\cos^20=1$, and consequently
$$\sin^2x,\:\cos^2x\le 1 \iff |\sin x|, \:|\cos x|\le 1.$$

Comment: I just want to point out that Spivak does not define sine that way, though that definition is part of the exercises.

Comment: @DonlansDonlans: I wasn't too sure whether it was in the  course or in the exercises (I don't have the book at hand, and I used it more than 20 years ago!). Thank you for clarifying this point!